# Hiding a subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website on a subdomain, and would like to hide the fact that it's a sub-domain. How can I do so?

For example, the site is www.example.com, and it's a sub-domain of www.mydomain.com. I don't want people to know that example.mydomain.com is the same as www.example.com. How do I hide this? With .htaccess? How?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

*www.example.com* is impossible to be a sub-domain of *www.mydomain.com*. I think you mean they point to the same IP address and, therefore, they point to the same website (or there are some kind of redirect).

A domain is simply, **example.com** or **mydomain.com**. Examples of sub-domains of these domains are: *www.example.com*, *mobile.example.com*, *whatever.mydomain.com* and they could, or not, point to the domain root.

I'll present you an example:

Google App Engine let's you chose a **appspot.com** subdomain, for instance, *myapp.appspot.com*. If you call this subdomain you access your website. But people usually want to use their own domain, or a subdomain, for instance, *myapp.mydomain.com*. Both subdomains will return the same content. If you'd wish to disable the **appspot.com** subdomain, you may follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1364733).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'proxy|P' (force proxy) flag.
Read the manual http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Note: mod_proxy must be enabled in order to use this flag.