# How to get the hostname in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm developing an app with Python on Google App Engine at
[http://shs1509-grc.appspot.com/](http://shs1509-grc.appspot.com)

And since I am in China, appspot is blocked, and my users have to use the hostname [http://shs1509-grc.appsp0t.com/](http://shs1509-grc.appsp0t.com) to visit my app.

The question is that when I use`self.redirect("/something")`, my users would be redirected to appspot, which they can't access,

but if use `self.redirect("http://shs1509-grc.appsp0t.com/something")`, users directly visiting appspot will be redirected to appsp0t, which is slower, and it will be troublesome for me to do local debugging.

I suppose I could solve the problem with `self.request.host` to get which hostname the visitor is from, but it seems that its value is still `shs1509-grc.appspot.com` even though I'm visiting from appsp0t. 

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `os.environ['HTTP_HOST'].endswith('.appspot.com')` and redirect accordingly. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364733/block-requests-from-appspot-com-and-force-custom-domain-in-google-app-engine) has more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But since `appsp0t` is actually a proxy server, I have worked out the way by redirecting according to the `self.request.remote_addr`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Glad you got it working! But, please, next time mention the proxy server in your question. :)