# Google cloud DNS: point naked domain to www?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-cloud-dns

I maintain the owon.ro domain which uses a simple App engine app.
I also we use google cloud dns.

These are the dns records:

1. A record with IP addresses:
   owon.ro. -> 
   216.239.32.21
   216.239.34.21
   216.239.36.21
   216.239.38.21
2. CNAME
   www.owon.ro. -> ghs.googlehosted.com.

And also some MX records.

The problem is that the app is reachable from the *www* subdomain and the help section states that those IP addresses should be in the A record for the naked domain to redirect to *www*, but it doesn't work.

I also tried to use @ wildcard for the A record but that doesn't work also.
If you go to owon.ro you will see a 404 page but the www subdomain works.

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: I presume you followed the GAE custom domain instructions (particularly step 5c instead of 5b): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en

Comment: This is how you do it: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373?hl=en

Comment: Yes @DanCornilescu I followed step 5b to get the www subdomain working. As I said there is a CNAME record that points *www* to *ghs.googlehosted.com*. If I go back to developers console >  custom domains and choose to also point the naked domain to my app engine app it tells me to add those four IP addresses as A records which I already have..

Comment: On a different domain I used Google apps so I was able to make the change as @AndreiVolgin suggested, but in this case I am not using Google apps, so I don't have access to Google admin

Comment: Yes, but did you also add the naked domain (in addition to the www one) - are they both listed as custom domains for the app? The 4 records are `an additional` requirement, not the `only` requirement. Note: I'm just guessing here, I'm also doing the redirect through google apps (but I ran through a similar exercise when I set that up - couldn't add the naked domain as I already had the www one, I had to remove the www one, add the naked one, then re-add the www one as a subdomain of the naked one)

Comment: Oooo. I see, you have to add the *www* and the naked domain from that page. Thanks a lot @DanCornilescu

Comment: Yep, I see your page now. I'll make it an answer :)

Comment: @DanCornilescu do you mind if I choose my answer as the correct one. I just want to get some basic rep points. I wanted to write a more detailed answer but the stupid SO wouldn't allow me to add more than 2 links because I don't have at least 10 rep points. Are you ok with that? Thanks for the help again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I've an issue, my app is able to redirect to www (subdomain) and naked both. I just want user to redirect from naked to www. I've done the exact same thing, provided the custom domain settings to my provider namecheap as well. But no luck, is there any way out? I'm new to GAE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer in the end thanks to Dan Cornilescu.

If you use Google Apps you can set up to redirect the naked domain to *www*.

If not, you will need to follow the steps by going to 
Console > App engine > Settings > Custom Domain. 
In here, at the second step, you will have to point *www* to the app (by using the second option) and clicking Add.
And then also point the naked domain to it by choosing the first option and clicking Add again.

So if I understand correctly you will server the app using *www* subdomain and the naked domain in contrast to redirecting the naked domain to *www* as in the Google apps case.

In the end, [my custom domain tab looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyr43.png).

And my [DNS records looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FqYR.png)

Comment: I've an issue, my app is able to redirect to https://www (subdomain) and naked both. I just want user to redirect from naked to www. I've done the exact same thing, provided the custom domain settings to my provider namecheap as well. But no luck, is there any way out? I'm new to GAE.

Comment: In my case I created services for stage environment before creating services for prod environments, so that I added stage.mydomain.com before mydomain.com. In consequence app engine wasn't working for my naked domain. I deleted the custom domains in app engine and added them again just like you explained and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The DNS operations suggested in step 5c ([documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en)) are not enough, you also need to actually **add** the naked domain to the GAE config (in addition to the `www` one) - step 5d.

> ```
> 5. Continue to the next step the Add new custom domain form, selecting the custom domain you want to point to your App Engine app:
>
>     a. Refresh the console domain page so it will list the domains properly.
>     b. If you want to use a subdomain, such as www, use the second option (http://www.example.com);
>     c. If you want to use a naked domain, use the first option to specify a naked domain (such as http://example.com).
>     d. Click Add to create the desired mapping.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To link the naked domain so it points to the www when you are NOT using appengine you simply add both the 'A' record and a '@' record pointing to the Google ips which are and look like this:

```
  A 300 
35.232.62.127

@ A 300 
216.239.32.21
216.239.34.21
216.239.36.21
216.239.38.21
```