# I need help getting a custom domain on google apps to work

Tags: google-app-engine

For several years I had custom domain working for my app on google apps. A year ago they changed the way data is stored forcing me to move to a different application name. Since then I have been unable to map the custom domain to my new google app.

Google developers console shows that I have added the 4 A records and the 4 AAAA records they ask for

I also added a CName record and when I ping www.erlandanderson.com it shows ghs,googlehosted.com 
When I hit the naked domain I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. When I hit the domain prefixed with www I get a 404 error.

the site can be accessed as http://erland-anderson2.appspot.com/ and it works.
Any bright ideas

Comment: Did you do through the *entire* GAE domain mapping procedure? Asking as it appears it's not always obvious, see this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826320/google-cloud-dns-point-naked-domain-to-www/34830367#34830367

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your domain is 'verified domain' with web-master tools. Then, you need to map both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses because parts of AppEngine is running on IPv6 and you cannot control it. Last comes the CNAME mapping of your app URI to `ghs.googlehosted.com` Once these three things are correct, you will be able to access your app over a custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

i just took a look at your dns records (erlandanderson.com i presume). These are my findings:

- You have a cname set up for your **www** subdomain, so that should work as long as you have "www.erlandanderson.com" setup as domain in your developers console
- I cannot see the A or AAAA records on your bare domain
- I see that you have the A and AAAA records for the wildcard (*) in your dns settings. Meaning everything except **www** (since it has a different config) is correctly configured. Note that there is a difference between *.youdomain.com and yourdomain.com. If you want to configure the latter you usually leave the subdomain part empty or put an '@' instead. So....

You need to add the A and AAAA records for the @ entry in your dns configuration.