# How can I Google App Engine performance improved?

Tags: google-app-engine

I currently has serviced my app in Korea.

But, my app is installed in us-central because GAE not supported install for Asia.

so, i suppose it is very slow because it is faraway from GAE.

If that's problem, how can I solve this problem?

please suggest to me... thank you.

Comment: so, is that a problem (you'll need to figure this out first)? If yes, use something else, at least until GAE is available in asia? Your question is misleading, it's not GAE is slow because of it's location but there's network latency overhead.

Comment: ok,  thanks for answer!!!

Comment: This *might* help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667339/why-custom-domain-myapp-com-which-replaces-myapp-appspot-com-took-so-long-to

Comment: thanks, Dan! I already has set CNAME "ghs.googlehosted.com"

Answer (score 2):

I have been using Google Cloud Platform for 4 years now, Including the Google App Engine. The performance of your application backend system can only be slow if the developer did not optimise the program well. I would suggest that you try out using some of the following key aspect in solving your problem:

- Try so much to use [MemCache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/examples) for requests that are common to users and do not require instant real time updates.
- Look at the algorithms you are putting in place. This is very important for your execution through put. For example lets say you want to run a search though a billion records, u can use quick search algorithms like QuickSort3way.
- Lastly look at the choice of database you are using. You could mix NoSQL with SQL if you were only using SQL. If you are into big data then use BigQuery. This way your application's performance can drastically increase and scale up enormously.