# How can I redirect www to non-www in Google Cloud?

Tags: redirect, web, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have already searched this question on stack overflow. 
How can I do it? Can someone explain it to me step by step?

Also, how can I get a certificate for my url for free? 
I use cloudflare as my dns provider.

Thank You!

Comment: Your question is actually two questions.  Both of them quite broad.  Try editing your question so that you're asking something more specific.  For example, what have you tried so far?  What is your setup?  What problems are you running in to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google cloud DNS: point naked domain to www?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826320/google-cloud-dns-point-naked-domain-to-www)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i found out by myself how to solve this problem. This has nothing to do with Google. On cloudflare i created under pagerule a redirect from the www address to the non-www address.

And under the tab "Crypto" i activate the setting: "Always use HTTPS".

So everything is fine. Thank you.