# Redirect *.appspot.com to custom domain: Google app engine (Django)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, seo

I'm directly putting here some sample code of mine to get better picture.

```
url.py

(r'^robots\.txt$', 'myapp.views.robots'),
(r'^$', 'myapp.views.home'),

views.py

def home(request):
...my code
return render_to_response(request, 'myapp/home.html', locals())

models.py
class user_sessions(db.Model):
   email_id = db.StringProperty(default='')
   user_id = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
   class Meta:
      db_table = 'user_sessions'
      verbose_name = 'User Session'
      verbose_name_plural = 'User Sessions'
   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.user_id
```

My website is hosted on **mydomain.com** & I can access the using **mydomain.appspot.com** too. But the main issue i'm facing with **SEO**.

in `robots.txt` i'm calling my `mydomain.com/sitemap.xml`

but when i search on google & sees the result then it shows the result with appspot url but not with my actual domain url.

Then i got an idea of to redirect appspot.com to mydomain.com

But really i don't know how to do that globally in my app.

Could anyone help out for the same?

Answer (score 1):

If your custom domain is working, add a canonical tag to your pages.  This should notify search engines which domain you prefer when same content is available from multiple domains.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element